# How to view GDP as a network graph?

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp

I was looking at the GDP by industry data at https://apps.bea.gov/iTable/iTable.cfm?reqid=150&step=2&isuri=1&categories=gdpxind

I'm curious how to view all these industries in a network.

For example, someone who owns a rental property may use their rental income to buy a car. So this would contribute to an arrow from the "real estate" industry to the "motor vehicle and parts" industry.

Someone who receives a social security payment may go out to eat at a resturaunt, the restaurant uses that money to pay a loan, etc.

So all these sectors would have arrows to and from each other.

Has anyone done research to look at this or produce some graph or visualization? I am curious what the sources and drains are in this graph or what kind of loops there are.

Comment: The problem is, people buy many things. The person receiving soc.sec. payments will eat at a restaurant, buy gasoline, pay the electric bill, etc. So I don't see how you can allocate their income to certain purchases.

Comment: @Daniel You could divide it proportionally to how much money is spent. So add up all the money any person or company in the forestry industry spends on resturaunts and that would be the arrow from forestry to restaurants.
The goal is to create a chart like https://www.data-to-viz.com/graph/chord.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for [Input-output models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input%E2%80%93output_model).

> In economics, an input–output model is a quantitative economic model that represents the interdependencies between different sectors of a national economy or different regional economies.

The representation of is numerical, not graphical, but other than this, it seems to be what you want.

Comment: I though I-O models were just for production; are there I-O models for income and expenditure?

Comment: IO tables include things like public and private consumption. Otherwise numbers wouldn’t even add up.